# Set date SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a lot of dates 
I need to set each date on the 05 day of the following month. 
Example:

03.04.2011 -> 05.05.2011 

04/31/2011 -> 05/05/2011 

How to add a month, I understand (ADD_MONTHS)

Thanks!

Comment: Where you have this dates?

Comment: Is there any fixed date format in your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `last_day(date_columne) + 5`

```
select last_day(sysdate) + 5 from dual;
```

Output:

```
last_day(sysdate) + 5
---------------------
05-MAY-14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(ClmName , INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS newDate FROM tableName
```

I how it Will be Helpful for you.